# How to handle IE download pop up with selenium webdriver without using autoIt and robot class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, automation

I have to run a script to download a specific file to the desired folder in Internet Explorer without using AutoIt and robot. Is there any other way than this. I am new to automation.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvJNc.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eey7.png)

Comment: As far as I know, WebDriver has no capability to access the IE Download dialog boxes presented by browsers when you click on a download link or button. But, we can bypass these dialog boxes using a separate program called "[wget](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/)". More details, you could check [this article](https://www.guru99.com/upload-download-file-selenium-webdriver.html).

Comment: I have already tried this . But no luck...having some error still

Comment: Which language are you using to do the web driver test, Java? As we can see that, if using the wget method, we should get the hyperlink href property first, then based on the url to download the file. Can you share the related code about how to download the file in your web page. Besides, I found a sample about download file using the robot class, it works well on my side, can you consider to use this method?

Comment: package Download_file.Download_file;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class file_IE_mini {

 //file downloaded but exit val not printed after waiting for a while
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver" , "IEDriverServer.exe");
  WebDriver dr= new InternetExplorerDriver();
  dr.get("http://demo.automationtesting.in/FileDownload.html");

Comment: System.out.println(dr.getTitle());
  
    // Use getAttribute() to obtain the "href" value of the download link and save it as a String variable. In this case, we named the variable as "sourceLocation".
        WebElement downloadButton = dr.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='btn btn-primary']"));
        String sourceLocation = downloadButton.getAttribute("href");

Comment: //Set-up the syntax for wget using the following command.
        //whatever you put after -P will be your destination. In this case, the downloaded file will be placed on the C drive
        String wget_command = "cmd /c C:\\Wget\\wget.exe -P D: --no-check-certificate " + sourceLocation;
        System.out.println(wget_command);
        
      //this line will call wget and will supply the command we specified 
        Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(wget_command);

Comment: //the waitfor() method is used to wait until wget completes the download
        int exitVal = exec.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Exit value: " + exitVal);
        dr.close();
  
  //dr.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='btn btn-primary']")).click();
 }

}

Comment: As I get output in console as:

Comment: Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
3.150.1.0
Listening on port 5726
Only local connections are allowed
Jun 01, 2020 4:38:58 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
File input - Multi select
cmd /c C:\Wget\wget.exe -P D: --no-check-certificate https://github.com//sakinala/AutomationTesting/raw/master/samplefile.pdf

Comment: it does not return the value of exitVal. and the file downloaded in the desired path halfway through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the following code, it works well on my side, please check it:

```
package seleniumtest; 

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import java.io.IOException;

public class testsample {

    //@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        //add the IE web driver path here..
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","E:\\webdriver\\IEDriverServer_x64_3.14.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");   

        WebDriver browser = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        //replace the URL of the web page here..
        browser.get("<website url>");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, 5);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("btnDowloadReport")));

        WebElement element = browser.findElement(By.id("btnDowloadReport")); 
        String downloadurl = element.getAttribute("href");
        System.out.println(downloadurl);

        String command = "cmd /c E:\\\\Temp\\\\wget.exe -P E:\\\\Temp\\\\output\\\\ --no-check-certificate " + downloadurl;

        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            process.getErrorStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

Note: please remember to change the web driver path, website url and the download folder to your owns.

The website html resource:

```
 <a id="btnDowloadReport" href="https://github.com//sakinala/AutomationTesting/raw/master/samplefile.pdf" >Download</a>
```

The result (it will download the file to the desired folder):

[image]

Comment: It runs perfectly fine.